# Java char Array - deleting elements

Tags: java, arrays, char

In Java, I want to delete certain elements from a char array so it does something like:

```
char[] Array1 = {'h','m','l','e','l','l'};
Array1 = //character index[2] to character index[5]
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Java you can't delete elements from an array. But you can either:

Create a new `char[]` copying only the elements you want to keep; for this you could use [`System.arraycopy()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) or even simpler[`Arrays.copyOfRange()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange%28char%5b%5d,%20int,%20int%29). For example, for copying only the first three characters of an array:

```
char[] array1 = {'h','m','l','e','l','l'};
char[] array2 = Arrays.copyOfRange(array1, 0, 3);
```

Or use a `List<Character>`, which allows you to obtain a sublist with a range of elements:

```
List<Character> list1 = Arrays.asList('h','m','l','e','l','l');
List<Character> list2 = list1.subList(0, 3);
```

Comment: how do u copy certain elements coz i want: 
'code'(char[] example = //first character to 3rd last.)

is there a range method or something?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Arrays.copyOfRange` like this:

```
array1 = Arrays.copyOfRange(array1, 2, 5);
```

More [info](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange%28char%5b%5d,int,int%29)

Answer (score 2):

**Java function to remove a character from a character array:**

```
String msg = "johnny can't program, he can only be told what to type";
char[] mychararray = msg.toCharArray();
mychararray = remove_one_character_from_a_character_array_in_java(mychararray, 21);
System.out.println(mychararray);

public char[] remove_one_character_from_a_character_array_in_java(
                           char[] original, 
                           int location_to_remove)
{
    char[] result = new char[original.length-1];
    int last_insert = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < original.length; i++){
        if (i == location_to_remove)
            i++;

        result[last_insert++] = original[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

The above method prints the message with the index 21 removed.  You could place this in a loop to remove multiple items.  Technically you are not deleting an item, you are creating a brand new char array with the item removed.  You have to step through the entire string for each remove which is very inefficient.

**Delete a character by index from a character array with StringBuilder in Java:**

```
String mystring = "inflation != stealing";
char[] my_char_array = mystring.toCharArray();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append(mystring);
sb.deleteCharAt(10);
my_char_array = sb.toString().toCharArray();
System.out.println(my_char_array);             //prints "inflation = stealing"
```

The above code removes the exclamation mark from the character array.  If you want to delete a RANGE of characters, use `sb.delete(10, 15);`

Comment: how could we do this with O(1) space?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method:

```
public static char[] copyArray(char[] original, int start, int length)
{
    char[] result = new char[length];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        result[i] = original[start + i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Or you could use [`Arrays.copyOfRange(char[], int, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange\(char[],%20int,%20int\)).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Arrays.copyOfRange(char[], starting index, ending index) method for you.

You can also view this --

http://www.codingdiary.com/developers/developers/diary/javaapi/java/util/SampleCode/CopyofRange8ArrayExampleCode.html